# Assigning a value to a variable outside of a while loop in a R user-defined function

Tags: r

It seems that I have a variable assignment problem when using the following code in a user-defined function.

The code below works fine and produces the right output when used directly in the R session:

```r
# Code 1
n <- 1
n_final <- n
while(n < 3){
    n_new <- n + 1
    n_final <<- c(n_final, n_new); n <- n_new
}
n_final
[1] 1 2 3
```

However, when trying to wrap the code in a function, I obtain a wrong output:

```r
# Code 2
fn <- function(){
   n <- 1
   n_final <- n
   while(n < 3){
       n_new <- n + 1
       n_final <<- c(n_final, n_new)
       n <- n_new
   }
   return(n_final)
}
fn()
# 1
```

I still obtain the wrong output when using the `assign` function:

```r
# Code 3
fn <- function(){
    n <- 1
    n_final <- n
    while(n < 3){
        n_new <- n + 1
        assign("n_final", c(n_final, n_new), envir = .GlobalEnv)
        n <- n_new
    }
    return(n_final)
}
```

How could I insert the first code mentioned above in a function and get the same output?

Answer (score 1):

`<<-` assigns to the global environment. When you call `n_final` inside the `fn()`, R first searches the function environment for a variable named `n_final`, and voila it finds:

```r
n <- 1
n_final <- n
# ie. n_final is always 1 in the fn() environment
```

A solution to your error would be to use `<-` instead:

```r
fn <- function(){
  n <- 1
  n_final <- n
  while(n < 3){
    n_new <- n + 1
    n_final <- c(n_final, n_new)
    n <- n_new
  }
  return(n_final)
}
fn()
```

Results in your expected output:

```r
#> 1 2 3
```

Comment: This is a duplicate answer?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the global assignment operator `<<-` and replace it with local `<-`

```
fn <- function(){
   n <- 1
   n_final <- n
   while(n < 3){
       n_new <- n + 1
       n_final <- c(n_final, n_new)
       n <- n_new
   }
   return(n_final)
}
fn()
[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: or you should use  `n_final <<- n`.

Comment: That might work but it's usually bad practice to use global assignment inside a function. Have to be very careful

Comment: yes, but in some cases, you have to use global assignment so I mentioned the problem in the code.